# Multiple WHERE conditions separated by OR operator

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone tell me why this query is not working.

```
SELECT msg.message, 
       users.fname, 
       users.id 
FROM   msg 
WHERE  ( 
              msg.f_init_id='1' 
       AND    msg.f_recv_id='2') 
OR     ( 
              msg.f_init_id='2' 
       AND    msg.f_recv_id='1') 
JOIN   msg.f_init_id=users.id
```

This the Error I get:

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "ID" at position 199)

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT `msg`.`message`,`Users`.`fname`,`Users`.`ID` FROM `msg` WHERE (`msg`.`f_init_id`='1' AND `msg`.`f_recv_id`='2') OR (`msg`.`f_init_id`='2' AND `msg`.`f_recv_id`='1') JOIN msg.f_init_id=Users.ID LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN msg.f_init_id=Users.ID LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Comment: Please learn the `JOIN` syntax & the use of alias. (p.s. Most backticks you used are unnecessary. )

Comment: the join comes before the where

Comment: Read about the [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) statement. `WHERE` comes after `FROM`, the joins come under the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tidy up your SQL statement using aliases, and remove extra backticks:

```
SELECT a.message, b.fname, b.ID FROM msg a
JOIN Users b ON a.f_init_id = b.ID
WHERE (a.f_init_id = 1 AND a.f_recv_id = 2) 
OR (msg.f_init_id = 2 AND a.f_recv_id = 1) 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Since the `f_init_id` and `f_recv_id` in `msg` table has data type `INT` (or other numeric types), the values don't require to be surrounded with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out execution by changing your query as:

```
SELECT `msg`.`message`,`Users`.`fname`,`Users`.`ID` 
FROM `msg` JOIN `Users` ON (Users.ID = msg.f_init_id) 
WHERE (`msg`.`f_init_id`='1' AND `msg`.`f_recv_id`='2') 
OR (`msg`.`f_init_id`='2' AND `msg`.`f_recv_id`='1') 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

A `JOIN` clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

`WHERE` clause comes after `JOIN`. `ON` clause used for specifying conditions for `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `JOIN` condition between tables, before the `WHERE` condition clause. I remove `backtick` for code simplicity here.

```
SELECT
    m.message,
    u.fname,
    u.ID
FROM 
    msg m
    JOIN Users u
        ON m.f_init_id = u.ID
WHERE
    (m.f_init_id = '1' AND m.f_recv_id = '2') 
    OR (m.f_init_id = '2' AND m.f_recv_id = '1')
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem on your JOIN syntax. You can do it this way or like @sinto already answered.

```
SELECT `msg`.`message`,`Users`.`fname`,`Users`.`ID`
    FROM `msg`, `Users`
    WHERE msg.f_init_id=Users.ID  AND
        ((`msg`.`f_init_id`='1' AND `msg`.`f_recv_id`='2') OR (`msg`.`f_init_id`='2' AND `msg`.`f_recv_id`='1')) AND LIMIT 0, 25
```

Since its a JOIN, I prefer the classic JOIN syntax (JOIN .... ON... )